# Trimming a string using an array of characters using C#

Tags: c#, string, character-arrays

When you use the **Trim()** method on a string object, you can pass an *array of characters* to it and it will remove those characters from your string, e.g:

```
string strDOB = "1975-12-23     ";
MessageBox.Show(strDOB.Substring(2).Trim("- ".ToCharArray()));
```

This results is "75-12-23" instead of the expected result: "751223", why is this?

**Bonus question**:
Which one would have more overhead compared to this line (it does exactly the same thing):

```
strDOB.Substring(2).Trim().Replace("-", "");
```

Comment: What would 1 Jan 1999 look like in the format:  1999-01-01 ?

Comment: Depends on what you do with it. In SQL Server any string passed in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format translates, e.g: '1999-01-01 12:00:00' will be 1 Jan 1999 @ 12AM. Your localization doesn't matter in that case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cause the trim function only trims characters from the ends of the string.

use Replace if you want to eliminate them everywhere...

Comment: Hence, the name "trim" :-) +1

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

> Returns a new string in which all
>   *leading* and *trailing* occurrences of a set of specified characters from
>   the current String object are removed.

I guess that's self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

`Trim` only removes characters from the beginning and end of the string.  Internal '-' characters will not be removed, any more than internal whitespace would.  You want `Replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered correctly Trim only trims characters from the start and end of the string.  Use:-

```
Console.WriteLine( strDOB.Substring(2, 8).Replace("-","") )
```

This assumes a fixed format in the original string.  As to performance, unless you are doing a million of these I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Trim removes only from start and end. Use Replace if u want to remove from within the string.